# Hadoop Madreduce : Hive Query/Mapreduce Job hanged in Accepted State

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have installed Hadooop2.1 with hive 2 on my MacOSx sierra. My join hive query is not fetching me results and getting hanged for a long time .getting -"ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.". What can be the reason and how can i resolve it

P.S : Pardon me for this question , if this is way too simple , I am completely newbie.

Also, I have checked similar questions and it has been suggested to check the memory/RAM availablity , i have done the same and also tried changing the rqd xml conf files as per suggestions.I dont find any memory related issue in my system.

Answer (score 0):

A job stuck in accepted state is due to insufficient memory.You can check the same in below:
http://resourcemanager:port/cluster/scheduler:

You can do the following:

- Clean some space and give more RAM
- Modify yarn-site.xml as below

  `<property> <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name> <value>2100</value> <description>Amount of physical memory, in MB, that can be allocated for containers.</description> </property> <property> <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name> <value>600</value> </property>`

Comment: I have already checked the RAM, abt 4 tha of RAM is available.and since it's on the local/host system (not using any VM), I thought it shouldn't cause any problems.as mentioned in the question I have already checked out few similar questions on stackoverflow.